# Create GCE persistent boot disk programmatically

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to use the API to create a persistent boot disk automatically. I have created disks, but according to the api documentation, I am supposed to give a fully qualified URL to the disk, but all I have is the disk name. Does anyone know how to get the fully qualified URL of the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all of your disks in a zone with [`compute.disks.list`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1beta16/compute.disks.list). The `selfLink` for each disk will contain the fully qualified URL for the disk. You can also get the same info for a particular disk when you know the name (as in your case) using [`compute.disks.get`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/compute/v1beta16/compute.disks.get).

The URL will also be returned from the call to `compute.disks.insert` as `targetLink`.